# Auth->login() always logging in user

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

In my AppController:

```
public $components = array('Auth' => array(
    'authenticate' => array('Blowfish')
),
```

In my UsersController:

```
public function login() {    

if($this->request->isPost()) {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        if($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->response->statusCode(200);
        }
        else {
            $this->response->statusCode(401);
        }
    }

}
```

And whatever data are POSTed to `/users/login` the reponse is always 200 and user is logged in. How I can force Auth not to login but check username and password in db?

Comment: what do you have inside your view?

Comment: Please make sure you are following the directions here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#using-bcrypt-for-passwords

Comment: Do you have something in `Auth->allow()` in your before filter for example?

Comment: For those of you who are lost in the eternal quagmire that is CakePHP's auth system, consider giving up and doing: $this->User->findByUsernameAndPassword() instead of Auth->login. It's not best practice, but it's reliable and you can still use encryption and make sure your actions/controllers aren't touched by unregistered users.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having troubles with blowfish too.

But, did you remember to change the way passwords are stored in DB?

You have to do this in your "User" model:

```
App::uses('Security', 'Utility');

class User extends AppModel {

public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    // Use bcrypt
    if (isset($this->data['User']['password'])) {
        $hash = Security::hash($this->data['User']['password'], 'blowfish');
        $this->data['User']['password'] = $hash;
    }
    return true;
}

}
```